# Opening a file in pwdir's folder in Python through Applescript

Tags: python, macos, scripting, file-io, applescript

Opening a file available in present working directory's temp folder in python

I tried

```
pwdir=os.getcwd()
tempdir=pwdir+"/temp/test.txt"
f=open(tempdir,'r+')
```

When I print the path of tempdir, it is showing up correctly and also the contents of file are also read.

When I try to combine this operation from an Applescript, which calls this python script. I get an error like this

```
f=open(pwdir1,'r+')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//temp/test.txt'" number 1
```

EDIT:

I am using Shell script from Applescript to call this pythonscript

```
do shell script "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/test.py"
```

EDIT:

Python Code:

```
tempdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp','htmlinput.html')
print tempdir
with open(tempdir) as f:
    html=f.read()
```

Python output from terminal:(works perfectly fine)

```
/Users/mymac/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Outlook Script Menu Items/temp/htmlinput.html
```

I am also able to see the file contents.

Applescript Code:

```
do shell script "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/'Outlook Script Menu Items'/new.py"
```

Applescript Error:

```
error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/Users/mymac/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Outlook Script Menu Items/new.py\", line 12, in <module>
    with open(tempdir) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/temp/htmlinput.html'" number 1
```

Comment: @eryksun same problem ..have updated question

Comment: Try what @eryksun suggested or what I suggested in my edit. Eryksun, you need to post answers more often instead of comments so I can upvote you.

Comment: @eryksun os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'temp', 'temp.txt') works..Thanks

Comment: @all If this is a rare question, this deserves an upvote right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Applescript -- or OS X in general. It looks like the script is being run from the root folder, and os.getcwd() returns '/'. The directory of the script itself is `sys.path[0]` or the dirname of the current module -- `dirname(__file__)` -- if it's a single script instead of a package. Try one of the following

```
import os, sys
tempdir = os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'temp', 'temp.txt')
```

or

```
import os
tempdir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'temp', 'temp.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

The double slash is your problem. The right way to join file and path names in Python is with `os.path.join`. Try:

```
tempdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp', 'test.txt')
```

Also, you should probably be doing:

```
with open(tempdir) as f:
```

which will make sure tempdir gets closed even if you have an error.

Edit:

We need to see what `tempdir` is when the script is invoked by the AppleScript, not when it is invoked from the terminal. If you do

```
tempdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'temp','htmlinput.html')
with open('/Users/mymac/Documents/temp.txt', 'w') as fwrite:
    fwrite.write(tempdir)
```

What exactly ends up in the file `/Users/mymac/Documents/temp.txt`?

Comment: @agf..Nope same error. which opens good in Python separately and there is also no problem in the shell script when I try it for a different file..

Comment: It looks from the error message like you're not just passing it `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp', 'test.txt')` or it wouldn't have that extra double quote and 'number 1'. Please try editing your post to add what `print os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp', 'test.txt')` shows and what __exactly__ you get as an error when you `open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'temp', 'test.txt'))`